# Batteries, open or made

Tags: batteries

Are batteries suppose to show open or shorted across the taps from positive to negative? I have 20 or so 1.45v 265 ah SAFT batteries that show half of them open and half shorted.

Comment: Flip your multimeter probes and report your findings. I suspect it is not unlikely that you will find the ones that read open now read short and vice versa.

Comment: Continuity testing is done by putting a small voltage across the probes and measuring the current. An active voltage source will throw off the reading.

Answer (score 4):

Multimeters aren't designed to measure resistance in a live circuit. The voltage that the battery puts out is confusing the meter.

To test a battery, put an appropriate load on it and measure the voltage that the battery produces.